# Unable to get GA data for Adwords by dateHour

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am trying to get Google Analytics data for this specific query with these dimensions and metrics:

```
metrics=['adClicks', 'adCost', 'transactions', 'transactionRevenue', 'RPC', 'CPC']
dimensions=['date', 'adwordsCampaignID']
```

I verified from the GA Dim/Metrics explorer:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

This query work. However, when I changed the dimension to `dataHour`, instead of `date`, the results for `adClicks`, `adCost` are 0s, and transactionRevenue are different.

Any idea why I might be seeing these differences when dimensions is `date` compared to `dateHour`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you a victim of sampling? Whenever you query for non-standard dimensions (e.g. `dateHour` vs. `date`) you risk running into sampling which might badly affect the accuracy of your data (I've seen e-commerce revenue go to $0 because of it).

Check your query results for the `containsSampledData` flag:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#sampling

Several ways to work-around sampling:

- Play with [`samplingLevel`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel) and see if that helps
- Break your query down into several smaller queries each querying for a shorter date range and re-combine the data on your server

Comment: 'containsSampledData': False I looked through the results and checked the flag to be False. So based on this the sampleLevel should not apply correct?

Comment: Indeed if `containsSampledData` is `false` then you are not being sampled. Do you see any patterns as to where the data is wrong: is it for specific dates, specific hours, or campaigns, or does it seem completely random across the board?

Comment: There seems to be no pattern in the data... still scratching my head.